# Issues with cflock or not to Lock

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

i had a cflock when i started getting an error:

```
has run into a timeout (50 seconds) and has been stopped.
```

Select all

Open in new window

- then i removed the cflock again i am getting the same error

any Idea why

added the cflock with dynamic names and now getting same error with this line added:

```
Open locks at this time (filereadwrite: 13).
```

not sure if cflock has anything to do:

because the code is like this:

```
<cflock name="initre" timeout="10" type="exclusive">
    <cfset application.tools = createobject("component","xyz").init()>
</cflock>
```

and inside the `application.tools`, i have another `function` which has a `cflock` to it but it is a `dynamic named lock`

inside that `cflock`, it calls another `method` which does some processing of returning me `struct` after inserting into database

i am using the dynamic lock with `type: exclusive and timeout: 10`

Comment: does people understand before they make "-1"

Comment: It takes more than 10 seconds to create an object? That seems very heavy. Is there any way to lighten it up?

Comment: What is the code inside the lock doing?

Comment: its calling another function to do an upload

Comment: So when your application starts, it must do this upload? Hmm. Can you do this asynchronously, or does it have be done exactly when the application starts?

Comment: Why the requirement of doing an upload specifically on app start versus later, as suggested?

Comment: Do you even understand WHY you are locking the code? Does the error still occur, when you remove all the `cflock` tags?

Comment: To @Alex's point, my entire career, I have tried to make the startup code tinkering with `application.*` variables as fast as possible. I am wondering what is so important that the whole app needs to be locked out.

Comment: i never understood properly the cflock and i do not want to use it, but i had to for some reason but even if i remove lock, i still get timeout error